# How AbstractControl object passes to another class?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have an class that is:

```
    import { MathValidators } from '../math-validators';

    export class EquationComponent implements OnInit {

     mathForm = new FormGroup(
        {
          a: new FormControl(EquationComponent.randomNumber()),
          b: new FormControl(EquationComponent.randomNumber()),
          answer: new FormControl(''),
        },
        [
          MathValidators.addition('answer', 'a', 'b'),
        ]
      );

    }
```

and also there is another class that is :

```
   import { AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';

    export class MathValidators {

    static addition(target: string, sourceOne: string, sourceTwo: string) {
     return (form: AbstractControl) => {
    console.log(form);
    return {addition: null}
        }
    }

}
```

My question is that in first class when

> MathValidators.addition('answer', 'a', 'b')

runs , in second class output of console.log(form) shows me objects which  are  FormControls in first class.

What is logic here ?

Comment: If i understand correctly MathValidators.addition is bound to form as your'd write .bind(this) before fat arrow functions went mainstream...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MathValidators.addition in this case is a [ValidatorFn](https://angular.io/api/forms/ValidatorFn) 
I think what happens behind the scenes is this

```
 MathValidators.addition.call(this.mathForm, ['answer', 'a', 'b'])();
```

Great article on [js execution context](https://medium.com/better-programming/understanding-the-this-keyword-in-javascript-cb76d4c7c5e8)

UPDATE: 
Actually, what happens is this:
your function MathValidators.addition returns a different function

```
return (form: AbstractControl)
```

that takes AbstractControl as parameter. That function is then called with this/FormGroup as a parameter